# what is npm doing differently when loading a project with a github url vs the usual npm install?

Tags: npm

There's an npm module I'm using, that works fine in my project when installed with npm and its semver, but that fails with the below error when I try to install it with its github url.

The error: `Uncaught Error: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be removing a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's`render`method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded`

I'm loading the same version of the module, not changing any build configs, the only difference is loading with semver vs github url.

I should say, the module's lib folder is not checked into github. So I do run a build of the module manually.

I'm using webpack for the build. I suspect its a problem with the copies of react being loaded, but that doesn't seem to have changed, and webpack seems to be handling duplicates.

npm ls react:

├── react@15.6.1
├─┬ react-color@2.2.0
│ └─┬ reactcss@0.4.6
│   └── react@0.14.9
└─┬ react-with-context@1.2.1
  └── react@15.6.1  deduped

A little confused, any tips appreciated

(If that makes any difference, the error seems to be thrown from a dependency of the module that I'm testing. And in both modules (the one I'm testing + its dependency), react is listed as a peerDependency package.json)

Comment: Versions in github repository and npm respository might differ. Projects usually have pre-publish hooks that build things.

Comment: Thanks! I compared the modules, and there were indeed some differences, but trivial ones. 

I did notice that in the npm package installed via github url, there were a few extra keys in the package.json:
"bundleDependencies": false,
"_inBundle": false

I tried without those keys as the package in the npm registry doesn't have them, but it still didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ended up just deleting react from the node_modules folder of the package, and it works